# Counting Ignite Physical Servers

Tags: sql, ignite

Newbie question, but not seeing a clear answer in the docs: I want to run a query on Ignite (2.13) that returns the number of physical ignite servers - despite Ignite running within containers.  I suspect this will require some inference, as Ignite reports IP address per server (container or physical).

Something like `Select * from sys.Nodes;` but somehow collapsing containers on the same server together.

Any thoughts?   Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such built in machinery, why would you need it?

I suppose you might do the following instead:

- mark all containers running at the same machine by a single [User Attribute](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cluster/ClusterNode.html), like `MY_SERVER_NUMBER_1`, `MY_SERVER_NUMBER_2`
- query the nodes and filter by unique attriubteId, something like:

  ```
   select count (distinct Name) from sys.NODE_ATTRIBUTES where Name like 'MY_SERVER_NUMBER_%'
  ```

Comment: Thanks Alexandr - to answer your question: I have a team that was supposed to start a 3n cluster, but instead gave me a 8n cluster... if it were free, that'd be fine, but we're paying for the clusters, and came with some sticker-shock.  I can solve the same problem reconciling the cloud vendor bill, but we have a lot of clusters and their tagging isn't great...  was hoping there's an easy way to divine instance count rather than container from the SQL interface directly, which would be the most definitive reconciliation.   anyway, thx!

Comment: Well, from your comment, the issue seems to be more about communication misleading between the teams. From the software's point of view, there is no difference in running it under a shared VM or on a dedicated bare metal server, it just sees the number of available resources. I suppose you might somehow get the real information from a user Java code and then compare it to the number of Ignite's nodes running in the topology. If that doesn't match, you are running several nodes on the same instance.

Comment: If you are just looking for non-SQL metrics of your topology ignoring the physical machines distribution, there are different APIs available, like https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring-metrics/new-metrics#cluster